# Как распарсить фрейм, приходящий в сообщении WebSocket серверу на си от браузера?

Tags: c, веб-программирование, сервер, websocket

Реализую свой WS сервер на си. После установки соединения с браузером и переключения на протокол WS пытаюсь отправить серверу сообщение. Оно передается вместе с фреймом, который занимает 6 байт и его нужно как то расшифровать. Как я понял, в отдельных битах фрейма содержитс информация о сообщении, но как распарсить этот фрейм я не имею понятия. Си воспринимает пришедшее сообщение как мусор и при выводе в консоль это выглядит примерно вот так 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На сообщение "123" приходит 9 байт, 6 байт фрейма и 3 байта самого сообщения, как распарсить это сообщение и привести к виду, с которым можно работать в си?

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455 здесь полностью описан стандарт вебсокетов

Comment: @Zergatul, я знаю, я не понимаю как расшифровать фреймы на си